# Real time video Broadcasting and Streaming

Tags: ios, xcode, api, video-streaming, rtsp

I would like to use a realtime video broadcasting app to a Media server. I prefer RTSP. Any idea which tool i can use for the same.

I found out some thing like:

from :http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/ios/index.html?asyncall.htm

```
-(void) initConnection {
 rtmpClient = [[RTMPClient alloc] init];
 rtmpClient.delegate = self;
 [rtmpClient connect:@"rtmp://192.168.0.11:2037/MyApp"];
}

-(void)connect:(id)sender {        
         upstream = [[BroadcastStreamClient alloc] initWithClient:rtmpClient];
         upstream.imageView = drawImage; // contains the current video frame
         upstream.delegate = self // must be an instance of IBroadcastStreamClientDelegate
 [upstream stream:@"MyStream" publishType:PUBLISH_LIVE];
}

-(void)disconnect:(id)sender {        
   [upstream disconnect];
   upstream = nil;
}

-(void)startPublish {
   [upstream start];
}

-(void)stopPublish {   
   [upstream stop];
}

-(void)pausePublish {
   [upstream pause];
}
```

As i haven't done  anything like this before,please suggest which tool/way is more **efficient** and fast.

Comment: Have you eventually found one for RTSP?